# Multiple SSH tunnels from different remote connections forwarding same port: Okay to do?

Tags: load-balancing, ssh-tunnel

I have a server running a service on port, say, 4444.

Normally, the software that utilizes this service is installed on the same server and connects via 127.0.0.1:4444, so there is no need for authentication.

However, I have installed this software on several remote servers globally so users local to those servers have faster access to the software, and achieve some load balancing.

I'm utilizing SSH tunnels to forward the main server's port 4444 to each remote server's port 4444 and then point the remote software to localhost:4444. Then using a firewall to prevent any other inbound connections.

This seems to work so far with just me connecting to the remote server and using the software, but I'd like to know if this is the ideal way to go about this or will I run into issues when multiple people are connected to each remote server?